# I have an outer div and a img tag inside this div. Now I want the content of this div without including the content of the img tag can anyone help me?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

A sample of HTML content:

```
<div class="content"> Hello World It is good to see you.<span>hi<img/></span></div>
```

I want to print only `"Hello World It is good to see you."` (should not include hi and img) but when I try methods like .text in BeautifulSoup, it is also scraping the text from the inner tags. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider:

```py
my_html = '<div class="content"> Hello World It is good to see you.<span>hi<img/></span></div>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(my_html)
div_tag = soup.find("div")
```

The following line will achieve it:

```py
text_content = div_tag.find_all(text=True, recursive=False)
```

Hope it helps.